# Can an empty MultiIndex be used to slice a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `MultiIndex` that I'm trying to use to slice a `DataFrame`. When the `MultiIndex` is empty, it results in a `ValueError`:

```
(Pdb) p _ix
MultiIndex(levels=[[], [], [], []],
       labels=[[], [], [], []],
       names=['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'raz'])
(Pdb) p df.index
MultiIndex(levels=[['adni'], ['123', '234'], ['M12_s1', 'M24_s1'], ['CRB', 'CRB_crop', 'PON']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
       names=['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'raz'])
(Pdb) p df.loc[_ix]
*** ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (4,) (0,)
```

The `names` of the two indices match, so from what I understand this slicing should be fine.

In some conditions when `_ix` isn't empty, this works as expected. I can't find anything in the documentation that describes not supporting an empty DataFrame like this though. Am I missing something obvious?

**Edit:** adding concrete example:

```
$ cat so_qc.csv
foo,bar,baz,raz,qc
pd,andrew,M24_s1,CRB,True
pd,andrew,M24_s1,CRB_crop,True

$ cat so_df.csv
foo,bar,baz,raz,value
pd,andrew,M24_s1,CRB,0.701794977111406
pd,andrew,M24_s1,CRB,0.309406238674409

$ python
qc = pd.read_csv('so_qc.csv', index_col=[0,1,2,3], squeeze=True)
df = pd.read_csv('so_df.csv', index_col=[0,1,2,3])

# This is OK
df.loc[ qc.index.intersection(df.index) ]

# When I select only False elements from `qc` (which is none of them), ValueError about broadcasting
df.loc[ qc[~qc].index.intersection(df.index) ]
```

Comment: Can you create a complete example?  MVCE?

Comment: I notice in my example that `df` doesn't have a unique index, and e.g., changing the 2nd row from `CRB` to `BLA`, this doesn't break.. maybe we're actually looking at a bug?